# Require exactly 1 trailing newline in a file

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

I have a mix of files with various ways of using trailing new lines.  There are no carriage returns, it's only `\n`.  Some files have multiple newlines and some files have no trailing newline.  I want to edit the files in place.

How can I edit the files to have exactly 1 trailing newline?

Comment: There are no UNIX tools that do real "in place" editing, they all create a temp file (or internal buffer in the case of `ed`) and overwrite the original with that. Is that a problem?

Comment: No, temp files are okay as long as its transparent.  I don't want to deal with backup files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change text files in-place to have one and only one trailing newline:

```
 sed -zi 's/\n*$/\n/'
```

This requires GNU sed.

`-z` tells sed to read in the file using the NUL character as a separator.  Since text files have no NUL characters, this has the effect of reading the whole file in at once.

`-i` tells GNU sed to change the file in place.

`s/\n*$/\n/` tells sed to replace however many newlines there are at the end of the file with a single newline.

Comment: But if there is no \n at the end of the file this won't add one

Comment: @harmic Yes, it will.  Because `\n*` matches _zero_ or more newlines, the command will add one even if none are present. What makes you say otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

Replace all trailing new lines with one?

```
$text =~ s/\n+$/\n/;
```

This leaves the file with one newline at the end – if it had at least one to start with.  If you want it to be there even if the file didn't have one, replace `\n+` with `\n*`.

For the in-place specification, implying a one-liner:

```
perl -i -0777 -wpe 's/\n+$/\n/' file.txt
```

The meaning of the switches is explained in [Command Switches in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).

---

Here is a summary of the switches.  Please see the above docs for precise explanations.

- `-i` changes the file "in place."  Note that data is still copied and temporary files used
- `-0777` reads the file whole. The `-0[oct|hex]` sets `$/` to the number, so to nul with `-0`
- `-w` uses warnigs.  Not exactly the same as `use warnings` but better than nothing
- `-p` the code in `''` runs on each line of file in turn, like `-n`, and then `$_` is printed
- `-e` what follows between `''` is executed as Perl code
  `-E` is the same but also enables [feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html)s, like`say`

Note that we can see the equivalent code by using core [O](http://perldoc.perl.org/O.html) and [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) modules as

```
perl -MO=Deparse -wp -e 1
```

This prints

```
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    '???';
}
continue {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

showing a script equivalent to the one liner with `-w` and `-p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -0 -pe 's/\n\n*$/\n/' input-file
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions posted so far read your whole input file into memory which will be an issue if your file is huge. This only reads contiguous empty lines into memory:

```
awk -i inplace '/./{printf "%s", buf; buf=""; print; next} {buf = buf $0 ORS}' file
```

The above uses GNU awk for inplace editing.